# A nested radical

Tags: calculus, limits, nested-radicals

> Find
>
> $$\large \lim_{n \to
>  \infty}\sqrt[3]{a_0+\sqrt[3]{a_1+\cdots+\sqrt[3]{a_n}}},$$ where
> $\large a_n=6(3^{3^n}+1)^2.$

According to Herschfeld's Convergence Theorem, the limit do exists , since $\large\dfrac{\ln a_n}{3^n}$ is bounded. But how to compute it?

Comment: In general, it is *much much* easier to show a limit exists than to compute it.  Why do you think this one can be computed (in any form other than the one already stated)?

Comment: Do you have a source for this question? I would prefer confirmation of the fact that this limit is computable exactly, than to resort to a numerical approximation.